# Swtiching from Selenium webDriver normal way to BDD Process of development for testing

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, bdd

I am using Selenium webdriver with TestNG and I build my scripts in Java. I am using Eclipse IDE to run my scripts. But now, I want to implement same scripts in BDD format. Is it possible? and how can I Implement? What are the tool that i'll need ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You may have a look in

- cucumber (afaik is the leader of such solutions at the moment) : http://cukes.info/
- jbehave : http://jbehave.org
- thucydides : https://java.net/projects/thucydides/

Comment: I installed Jbehave, but I started today on BDD, and have never used it before, can I know, how to run scripts in java and run them in eclipse using jbehave.

Comment: Didn't work yet with JBehave but possibly this [article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/behavior-driven-development-bdd-with.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+JavaCodeGeeks+%28Java+Code+Geeks%29) helps

Comment: this could be a **comment** instead of an answer, try to explain the links you provided to OP, where in the page is the info he/she needs and post it here. So Aruna is not the only one who will benefit from this question but future people that look at this question

Comment: I need to know, how to build class path before running these scripts and I want to know, which .jar and libraries we have to add while building path.

Comment: @Frankcool The question was generic about tool/s and to my point couldn't be answered in just a few lines, this is why I suggested tools as asked and provided a related article describing the usage of one of these tools. A detailed suggested solution would be too big to be included in the answer of such a generic question though...

Comment: I need to know, how to build class path before running these scripts and I want to know, which .jar and libraries we have to add while building path. Created New java project in Eclipse , then created a package & class.Created a .story file, by adding some steps in notepad++. The I have added selenium jar files and I have downloaded jbehave bin and src zip files, not sure, which jar files need to be added. So it will be appreciated if I can't get step by step direction to run scripts in BDD format.

Comment: @Aruna there are already threads providing details about JBehave, please have a look in [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150827/sample-jbehave-code-for-beginners)

Comment: Using jbehave , I was able to reach half the way like, I was able to write story, java class, and build path by adding jbehave jar file and junit in Eclipse IDE.